# For two random variables $X$ and $Y$, how can we show $max(X,Y)$ mathematically?

Tags: random-variables

Let us say we have $X$ and $Y$ two independent random variables.
How can we show $Z = min(X, Y)$ or $Z=max(X, Y)$ mathematically to find the mean and pdf of $Z$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the proceeding for $Z=\max(X,Y)$

$$F_Z(z)=\mathbb{P}[Z\le z]=\mathbb{P}[X\le z,Y\le z]=\dots\text{ using independence }\dots=\mathbb{P}[X\le z]\cdot\mathbb{P}[Y\le z]=F_X(z)\cdot F_Y(z)$$

can you do a similar reasoning for $U=\min(X,Y)$?

Comment: I did not understand how you can simply do and in place of max?
Also, I only have X and Y. how can I evaluate $F_X(z)$ and $F_Y(z)$ without knowing $Z$? The question is how can I write $Z$ using $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Please read well what I wrote. Here $z$ is simply a value, not a rv

Comment: Here it is for $U =  min(X,Y)$,
$$F_Z(z)=\mathbb{P}[Z\le z]=\mathbb{P}[X\ge z,Y\ge z]=\dots\text{ using independence }\dots=\mathbb{P}[X\ge z]\cdot\mathbb{P}[Y\ge z]=(1-F_X(z))\cdot (1-F_Y(z))$$

Comment: You are almost there. You found $P(Z>z)$.Thus $F_Z(z)$ is the complement. $F_Z(z)=1-(1-F_X(z))(1,F_Y(z))$

Comment: how dies min and max relate to $\le, \ge$ signs?

Comment: Observe that if max is < z then all rv are themselves <z. In the same way, if min is greater than u, all rv are themselves >u

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131089/discussion-between-atif-ali-and-tommik).